# Bitwise Operations in C: Can't figure out why XOR does not work. Is my code or logic flawed?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I can only use the bitwise operators mentioned below to create the described function:

```
/* 
*  allEvenBits - return 1 if all even-numbered bits in word set to 1
*  Examples allEvenBits(0xFFFFFFFE) = 0, allEvenBits(0x55555555) = 1
*  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >> 
*  Max ops: 12
*  Rating: 2    
*/
```

We are using 2s complement, 32-bit representations of integers. Also, I can only use integer constants 0 through 255 (0xFF), inclusive. My brute solution is the following:

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
  int mask0 = 0x55;
  int mask1 = 0x55 << 8;
  int mask2 = 0x55 << 16;
  int mask3 = 0x55 << 24;
  return(!(x ^ (mask0 | mask1 | mask2 | mask3)));
}
```

So I basically created a 0x55555555 mask, XOR the mask with x, and negate this operation assuming that the only time `(x ^ 0x55555555)` equals 0 is if x equals 0x55555555. (Based on the XOR property that `x ^ x == 0`.)

Therefore, when `x == 0x55555555`, this should be the only time my function returns 1. And it does return 1 when `x == 0x55555555`.

However, my function is incorrect, and I cannot figure out why. Is my logic flawed or is it my code?

Comment: Are you sure the function shouldn't return 1 if all even bits plus some other bits are set?  For example 0xFFFFFFFF seems like it should return 1.

Comment: Why come up with multiple int's if a single int can hold your value which is `0x55555555` and do it like `int mask = 0x55555555; return (!(x ^ mask));`

Comment: are you not allowed to use int literals larger than 0xFF?

Comment: and your logic is false since it disregards any odd bit existence

Comment: Why do you say that the "function is incorrect"?  Especially just after saying that it *does* work.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, I cannot use int literals larger than 0xFF. So from 0 to 255.

Comment: you can easily fill the constant to a 32-bit int in 2 shifts

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Good point. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This `allEvenBits` thing seems to be generating lots of questions, some teacher made the homework too hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're toggling the even bits and then compare the result with 0. However even when all the even bits are 1s, the odd bits are still unchanged, so whenever an odd bit is 1, your function will return 0. It only works correctly when all the odd bits are 0s

```
return (!(x ^ (mask0 | mask1 | mask2 | mask3)));
```

You need to clear all the odd bits either

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
  int mask = 0x55;
  int mask = mask | (mask << 8);
  int mask = mask | (mask << 16);

  return !(x & mask);
}
```

Another way

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
  int mask = 0xAA;
  int mask = mask | (mask << 8);
  int mask = mask | (mask << 16);

  return !((x | mask) ^ (~0));
}
```

Another shorter way

```
x &= x >> 16;
x &= x >> 8;
return !((x & 0x55) ^ 0x55);
// or return !(((x | 0xAA) + 1) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped illuminate a very important point that I was missing. I did not consider that odd bits could still be 1, so long as all of the even bits were 1. I would upvote you if I could.

Comment: I added another shorter way, you can try that

Answer (score 2):

Going by the problem statement rather than your prescription that the function should only return 1 for 0x55555555, here's one way:

```
int allEvenBits(int x) {
  int filled = x | 0xAAAAAAAA;
  return !(filled + 1);
}
```

We bitwise OR the input with a value which has all the odd bits set.  Therefore, if all the even bits in the input were set, we get 0xFFFFFFFF.  We then increment by one to overflow and get 0, which we finally negate to get the result.  Incrementing any number other than 0xFFFFFFFF will give a non-zero result, which when negated will be 0.

Comment: +1 for short and efficient way. But strictly speaking, signed overflow is undefined behavior, so `return !(filled + 1U);` will be better. And you should construct 0xAAAAAAAA from multiple shifts because the OP isn't allowed to use such large constants

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get a platform-independent mask of all even bits in an int set to one:
#define MASK ( (unsigned int) 0x55555555u )

/* MASK will be 0x5555u or 0x55555555u depending on sizeof(int).
   And then the actual algorithm: */
unsigned int allEvenBits(int x) 
{
  return (unsigned int)( !(x ^ MASK) );
}
```

Comment: `==` is not an allowed operator

Comment: the OP is not allowed to use integer literals larger than 0xFF either, so you'll end up with exactly the same way as him